# Странная избирательность switch конструкции

Tags: java, switch, final

Есть такой код, всё работает.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int num = 0;

        switch (num) {
            default:
                System.out.println("default");
            case num: //нет проблем
                System.out.println("case1");
            case 10 * 2 - 10:
                System.out.println("case2");
                break;
        }
    }
```

но стоит сделать вот такую импровизацию

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int num;
        num = 0;

        switch (num) {
            default:
                System.out.println("default");
            case num:  // Constant expression required
                System.out.println("case1");
            case 10 * 2 - 10:
                System.out.println("case2");
                break;
        }
    }
```

и воаля... появилась ошибка.

Интересно, получается, что в случае инициализации финального поле не во время объявления, то оно перестаёт быть финальной.

**Уточню:** пробовал после одной поздней инициализации ещё раз инициализировать, чтобы увидеть, вдруг по какой то магии можно будет более одного раза инициализировать финальное поле. В итоге нет, всё нормально. Инициализировать можно только один раз.

Ну ладно, тогда на каком основании switch не признаёт переданное значение как финальное??

Comment: Зачем вы используете модификатор `final` с переменной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компилятору надо знать значения, указанные в `case`-ах, во время компиляции. Для инициализированной `final` переменной (константы) - это требование выполняется. Для переменной, которая может принять в run-time любое значение, - нет.

Comment: Хорошо. Попробовал и через static final в теле класса, вне psvm. Вспомнил, что  во время обьявления если можно инициализировать, то только обьявлять а потом в этом самом теле класса инициализировать не получится, как то логически все связалась во едино.  В смысле вопрос снят. Спасибо за качественный ответ. Кратко и четко.

Comment: если что то недопонял с вашей точки зрения, скажите.